# TS2322: Generic not propagated correctly

Tags: typescript, json-api

We use [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) as the main serialization schema for our API. Without going into the specifics, it mandates JSON responses from a server to have a top-level `data` property that may contain a single entity *or* an array of entities:

```json
// Single item
{ "data": { "id": 1 } }

// Collection of items
{ "data": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
] }
```

I encoded this schema into TypeScript types, so we can properly type API responses. This has yielded the following:

```js
// Attributes as the base type for our entities
type Attributes = Record<string, any>;

// Single resource object containing attributes
interface ResourceObject<D extends Attributes> {
    attributes: D;
}

// Collection of resource objects
type Collection<D extends Attributes> = ResourceObject<D>[];

// Resource object OR collection, depending on the type of D
type ResourceObjectOrCollection<D extends Attributes | Attributes[]> = D extends Array<infer E>
    ? Collection<E>
    : ResourceObject<D>;

// A response with a resource object or a collection of items of the same type
interface ApiResponse<T> {
    data: ResourceObjectOrCollection<T>;
}
```

A [response](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level) always contains a `data` property that may be a single [resource object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects), or a collection of resource objects.
A resource object always contains an `attributes` property that holds arbitrary entity attributes. The purpose of all typing here is to propagate the attributes structure by passing entity interfaces as the generic `T`, as illustrated by the following examples:

```js
interface Cat {
    name: string;
}

function performSomeApiCall<Ret>(uri: string): Ret {
    return JSON.parse(''); // Stub, obviously
}

function single<T extends Attributes = Attributes>(uri: string): ApiResponse<T> {
    return performSomeApiCall<ApiResponse<T>>(uri);
}
```

The `single` function fetches a response from an endpoint that returns a single entity - say, `/api/cats/42`. Thus, by passing the `Cat` interface the type of data correctly resolves to a single resource object:

```js
const name: string = single<Cat>('/api/cats/42').data.attributes.name;
```

We can also define a function that returns multiple entities:

```js
function multiple<T extends Attributes = Attributes>(uri: string): ApiResponse<T[]> {
    return performSomeApiCall<ApiResponse<T[]>>(uri);
}
```

This function returns a collection of `T`s, so the following is valid, too:

```js
const names: string[] = multiple<Cat>('/api/cats').data.map(item => item.attributes.name);
```

What does *not* work, however, is defining a function that retrieves the attributes of a single entity directly, and that is what I don't understand:

```js
function singleAttributes<T extends Attributes = Attributes>(uri: string): T {
    return single<T>(uri).data.attributes;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

> Type 'Record<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'Record<string, any>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, any>'. (2322)

Why does Typescript understand the `single` function returns a resource object for T, but not for `singleAttributes`? Somewhere, it seems to drop the generic type in favor of the base type of `Attributes`, but I don't get why or where.

Check out [the playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/PTAEEEBdIJwSwEYFdIFMDOoCGnIAtVQEdDIBPAB0IDMB7GUWpB1AO0jg4wChyqJo8ZGkwBeUACVUAY3oATADzpYcVgHMANNlZkAfAG5u3EKADKqtQBtCMDExjTCtBACsZkULPZZVF7IMQUHlU0GGosR0k7ZkcAeVd3BQARUFQADzRWOUwoFWEMXVAAb25QMv88oPQALlAkwwBfIxMAYVpLa2kOWlZGalBbdHtI5zcu9F5KQjaO9zge5NSMtmyBSpFC8SkhmNR4schk3QBtAF1DYzBt4acErtBYiU92zu7WLTlUKiy-HtB8UhTPp1Sb8a67fbuWIwGaveasRbpTKrXJCKqgAA+azRIjOmzqS2RORgMCwZAUqmoqAYAFFdKVygB+UCwuYLOkMsq1cEOPZ3Q5JAzNMDgAYYCg9dCEADunDw2DFO15jH5jAYWGesy68OBnFQAFtMLR+gDQOgsPrAVRuCFqeFIuAKHBthLWFKFAAVQolcqgORYSBYbnRXmQrrQ1nahZexpGW1hCLTAPFTmgVgW1C1ZTwdSx7jUJCsKO9Khhej60y0S2OuAtLAdBRSSC6AAUzDgWZU6gAlMGPD7yrZIMxegApUyxAByADoKFgYFK2-Bu-pQCZTMOEFpnAA3eZIdCWMjcJr5wvFs0WayewkrHIBfJibGBDZLjtmrtqXsQJ0uyWoT1vVTIcR1AUs6BgCsq1QGs6wbGs-zdACvVbdsVxPIwvGUTwA0nDNOxzNRQHEdArwAutmxbAByYAsCdYBpADdBgAAFgAJio7tp39QNpwDdYMGndNLQuAsizeUB9SQSwOAoa8PVvLJ7wEp9URfAo3wIixvwQ8V-09PEU19ECYBLO1y0rasnTgywFF09BXXdD08VQ5c8ywjxGMgPDLRqD9CLOYjJOk2Trwo1saLouAGKYzjuIDLBp31OiW1TPV9WIwp0r4h8qiEjNuHQs9xJ1Uj1GsNTHxvJE72fR8gsqqpXPfbNtNqBSBzKEzejKqxkOarieMS-icQwRogA) for a demo of the problem.

Comment: try to remove explicit return type from `singleAttributes`. In most cases TS should infer return type

Comment: that seems to work, but I'm still curious why `T` isn't statically valid as the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type of

```js
function singleAttributes<T extends Attributes = Attributes>(uri: string): T {
    return single<T>(uri).data.attributes; < --- Record<string, any>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

is in fact `Record<string, any>`

See next example:

```js
function singleAttributes<T extends Attributes>(uri: string): T {
    let ret = single<T>(uri).data.attributes

    let t: T = null as any;
    ret = t; // ok
    t = single<T>(uri).data.attributes // error
}
```

> Type 'Record<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'Record<string, any>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, any>'.

`T` is assignable to return value, but return value is not assignable to `T`. That's why you can use `T` as an explicit type for return type

`T` could be much wider type.

Se example:

```js
type WiderType = Record<string | symbol, any> extends Record<string, any> ? true : false // true


type WiderType2 = Record<string, any> extends Record<string | symbol, any> ? true : false // true
```

When you expect `Record<stirng, any>`, `T` can be `Record<string | symbol,any>` as well. Or even `Record<string | symbol | number, any>`

**In order to make it work**

just use wider type from the start:

```js
function singleAttributes<T extends Record<string | symbol | number, any>>(uri: string): T {
    return single<T>(uri).data.attributes
}
```

or remove explicit return type

I'd say that `Record<string, any>` is pretty much the same as `Record<number, any>` because it will be infered to string according to js specification.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17509#issuecomment-318839759) you have great explanation

> This is working as intended and is a result of the stricter checks introduced in #16368. In your example, the IMyFactoryType (or the interface, they're structurally identical) represents a function that is supposed to return exactly typed values of any type that derives from IMyObject, even though the function doesn't actually have any parameters involving T that would allow it to discover what T is and create an appropriate return value. In other words:

Comment: What made it click for me is the code comment in your linked issue: _T could be any type that derives from IMyObject, but there's no way to discover what T is because it isn't used in a parameter type._

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc

I'm gathering all links regarding to covariance/variance and inveriance. I'd willing to bet that it will be interesting for you